# POS tagging in spanish with NLTK?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

Im new with NLTK library and i was wonder if it´s possible to make a POS-tag task with a spanish corpus with NLTK. Making some reasearch at the web i found [spaghetti-tagger](https://code.google.com/p/spaghetti-tagger) but it only has bigram and unigram taggers. Is it possible to use NLTK in order to POS-tagging a spanish corpus?.

Comment: what other machine learning methods / features do you need to train your desired spanish tagger? I could try my best to add new algorithms/features to the `spaghetti-tagger` when i'm free. BTW, thank you for looking into the spaghetti-tagger, i wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using a native Python implementation of [TnT](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tag/tnt.py) or a wrapper of [Hunpos](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tag/hunpos.py): both should work well.

However, there is another tool called [PurePos](https://github.com/ppke-nlpg/purepos), which I develop, written in JAVA and it has a [Python interface](https://github.com/ppke-nlpg/purepos.py) as well. There is a [demo](https://github.com/ppke-nlpg/purepos.py/blob/master/src/purepos/demo.py) which can help you to start with tool.

Comment: should i install it with pip?. Does it has support for spanish language?.

Comment: I suggest downloading the Python wrapper from the repository then you can involve it to a project. (It has no yet been published.)

It is intended to be language independent (very similar to TnT or HunPos). All you need is an annotated corpus, then you can start training the tool, and using it for tagging.

Comment: do you have any tutorial to start using it?.